# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 9 were given

Tags: python-3.5

when l run the following program l got this error :

```
 originDataset = dataset.lmdbDataset(originPath, 'abc', *args)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 9 were given
```

This error is relate to the second code source l presented below. it's strange because l don't have 9 argument. what's wrong with my code ?

```
import sys
origin_path = sys.path
sys.path.append("..")
import dataset
sys.path = origin_path
import lmdb

def writeCache(env, cache):
    with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
        for k, v in cache.iteritems():
            txn.put(k, v)

def convert(originPath, outputPath):
    args = [0] * 6
    originDataset = dataset.lmdbDataset(originPath, 'abc', *args)
    print('Origin dataset has %d samples' % len(originDataset))

    labelStrList = []
    for i in range(len(originDataset)):
        label = originDataset.getLabel(i + 1)
        labelStrList.append(label)
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print(i)

    lengthList = [len(s) for s in labelStrList]
    items = zip(lengthList, range(len(labelStrList)))
    items.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])

    env = lmdb.open(outputPath, map_size=1099511627776)

    cnt = 1
    cache = {}
    nSamples = len(items)
    for i in range(nSamples):
        imageKey = 'image-%09d' % cnt
        labelKey = 'label-%09d' % cnt
        origin_i = items[i][1]
        img, label = originDataset[origin_i + 1]
        cache[labelKey] = label
        cache[imageKey] = img
        if cnt % 1000 == 0 or cnt == nSamples:
            writeCache(env, cache)
            cache = {}
            print('Written %d / %d' % (cnt, nSamples))
        cnt += 1
    nSamples = cnt - 1
    cache['num-samples'] = str(nSamples)
    writeCache(env, cache)
    print('Convert dataset with %d samples' % nSamples)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert('/share/datasets/scene_text/Synth90k/synth90k-val-lmdb', '/share/datasets/scene_text/Synth90k/synth90k-val-ordered-lmdb')
convert('/share/datasets/scene_text/Synth90k/synth90k-train-lmdb', '/share/datasets/scene_text/Synth90k/synth90k-train-ordered-lmdb')
```

which calls the following program :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

import random
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import sampler
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import lmdb
import six
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


class lmdbDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, root=None, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.env = lmdb.open(
            root,
            max_readers=1,
            readonly=True,
            lock=False,
            readahead=False,
            meminit=False)

        if not self.env:
            print('cannot creat lmdb from %s' % (root))
            sys.exit(0)

        with self.env.begin(write=False) as txn:
            nSamples = int(txn.get('num-samples'))
            self.nSamples = nSamples

        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.nSamples

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        assert index <= len(self), 'index range error'
        index += 1
        with self.env.begin(write=False) as txn:
            img_key = 'image-%09d' % index
            imgbuf = txn.get(img_key)

            buf = six.BytesIO()
            buf.write(imgbuf)
            buf.seek(0)
            try:
                img = Image.open(buf).convert('L')
            except IOError:
                print('Corrupted image for %d' % index)
                return self[index + 1]

            if self.transform is not None:
                img = self.transform(img)

            label_key = 'label-%09d' % index
            label = str(txn.get(label_key))

            if self.target_transform is not None:
                label = self.target_transform(label)

        return (img, label)


class resizeNormalize(object):

    def __init__(self, size, interpolation=Image.BILINEAR):
        self.size = size
        self.interpolation = interpolation
        self.toTensor = transforms.ToTensor()

    def __call__(self, img):
        img = img.resize(self.size, self.interpolation)
        img = self.toTensor(img)
        img.sub_(0.5).div_(0.5)
        return img


class randomSequentialSampler(sampler.Sampler):

    def __init__(self, data_source, batch_size):
        self.num_samples = len(data_source)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __iter__(self):
        n_batch = len(self) // self.batch_size
        tail = len(self) % self.batch_size
        index = torch.LongTensor(len(self)).fill_(0)
        for i in range(n_batch):
            random_start = random.randint(0, len(self) - self.batch_size)
            batch_index = random_start + torch.range(0, self.batch_size - 1)
            index[i * self.batch_size:(i + 1) * self.batch_size] = batch_index
        # deal with tail
        if tail:
            random_start = random.randint(0, len(self) - self.batch_size)
            tail_index = random_start + torch.range(0, tail - 1)
            index[(i + 1) * self.batch_size:] = tail_index

        return iter(index)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples


class alignCollate(object):

    def __init__(self, imgH=32, imgW=128, keep_ratio=False, min_ratio=1):
        self.imgH = imgH
        self.imgW = imgW
        self.keep_ratio = keep_ratio
        self.min_ratio = min_ratio

    def __call__(self, batch):
        images, labels = zip(*batch)

        imgH = self.imgH
        imgW = self.imgW
        if self.keep_ratio:
            ratios = []
            for image in images:
                w, h = image.size
                ratios.append(w / float(h))
            ratios.sort()
            max_ratio = ratios[-1]
            imgW = int(np.floor(max_ratio * imgH))
            imgW = max(imgH * self.min_ratio, imgW)  # assure imgH >= imgW

        transform = resizeNormalize((imgW, imgH))
        images = [transform(image) for image in images]
        images = torch.cat([t.unsqueeze(0) for t in images], 0)

return images, labels
```

Comment: Yes you do. You have the instance, the two fixed arguments, and the 6 from the expansion.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, don't understood your  comment

Comment: How about removing the `*` in `dataset.lmdbDataset(originPath, 'abc', *args)`?

Comment: thanks it works after removing * . @kitman0804 could you explain why it works after removing * ?

Comment: Without `*`, it means you are doing `dataset.lmdbDataset(originPath, 'abc', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`. With `*`, you are doing `dataset.lmdbDataset(originPath, 'abc', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`, and `imdbDataset` allows at most 3 arguments, that's why you go an error.